# UPDATE statement in a VIEW?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a long view consisting of mostly SELECT statement within CTES.  One of the CTEs I have takes too long to execute so I've decided to store the results in a Table.  Is there anyway I can UPDATE this table at least once a day when the query is ran?

This is what I used to Create the Table:

```
WITH NetNewCustomers AS
    (
        SELECT
            CustomerId
            , DateFirstPurchase
            , PurchaseDate
            , PurchaseId
        FROM 
            AllCustomerPurchases
        WHERE
            PurchaseDate = DateFirstPurchase


    )


    SELECT 
        * 
    INTO 
        [GuitarMarketing].[dbo].[NetNewCustomers] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
             * 
        FROM 
            NetNewCustomers 
    ) 
        AS CTE
```

I tried creating a stored procedure something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NetNewCustomers) DROP TABLE NetNewCustomers;

WITH NetNewCustomers AS
    (
        SELECT
            CustomerId
            , DateFirstPurchase
            , PurchaseDate
            , PurchaseId
        FROM 
            AllCustomerPurchases
        WHERE
            PurchaseDate = DateFirstPurchase


    )


    SELECT 
        * 
    INTO 
        [GuitarMarketing].[dbo].[NetNewCustomers] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
             * 
        FROM 
            NetNewCustomers 
    ) 
        AS CTE

  END
```

But not I'm not sure how to get this stored procedure or code to run when ever this code is ran. Eventually I want to add logic that will check if query has been ran today or not. If it's been ran today then don't create this table again.

Comment: Use the job agent? Triggers?

Comment: Use a SQL Server Agent Job to run it daily.

Comment: Would this have to run on the dedicated server? I only have read/create access for tables and views from the Desktop Management Studio....

Comment: The trigger would need to run after any DML. I would ideally want it to run after SELECT if this is possible

Comment: Maybe create a stored proc that (1) Returns the data you want, THEN (2) Does the update if it hasn't already run today, then you use the stored proc instead of a select statement to get your data...

Comment: There's definitely no such thing as a SELECT trigger.  BTW, are you asking because you think it will be faster to use the CTE to update a table and then select from the table than it will be to select from the CTE?   Because it sounds like this is what you want to do every time someone queries the view.

Comment: @TabAlleman That part of the query doesn't have to run every time someone runs the query. But other parts might.

Comment: In that case, it's completely unclear to me what you're asking.   Maybe one of the answerers below guessed right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in solution to this problem is called a *materialized view* (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view)).  These are views that are materialized (stored as a table/cache).  The views can be updated incrementally, or they can be re-built on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessarily long view.

Why do you have sub table that is noting but a select of a table?

Why are you dropping the table.  Truncate is faster than drop and create.

```
insert INTO [GuitarMarketing].[dbo].[NetNewCustomers] 
SELECT    CustomerId
        , DateFirstPurchase
        , PurchaseDate
        , PurchaseId
FROM  AllCustomerPurchases
WHERE PurchaseDate = DateFirstPurchase
```

If there are index on PurchaseDate and DateFirstPurchase that should be fast.
Not understanding why you need to materialize that.